# What is the highest SELinux privilege(role)?

Tags: openssh, selinux

I want to know what role is the highest role of SELinux.

If I am mistaken, can anyone tell me what roles are available by default in SELinux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Welcome to ring 0!** btw, you will need RBAC for role based restrictions. You did guess it? RBAC comes from Role Based Access Control, there is others too.

First of all you should really read about SELinux as it can be dangerous to just set/get privileges without knowing effects. See for example [Hardened Gentoo Handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/hardened/selinux/selinux-handbook.xml).

I think that highest role is simply what you have given most access permissions...
There is other solutions too, for example [grsecurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grsecurity) also has its RBAC system. Gentoo Handbook first states that `system_r` is highest of default levels, however it has some restrictions too. You should go through manuals and define your roles as needed.

Here's article about *[RBAC in SELinux](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-rbac-selinux/)* from IBM Linux Technology Center.

And here is few lines from Gentoo Handbook:

> The system_r role is used for highly privileged system services. The
>   system_r role is allowed to switch to any other "default" role. No
>   role exception sysadm_r can switch to the system_r role.